# String Compare with special characters

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to compare two strings along with hyphen characters and find out the correct breaking point

Case 1:

```
dim Dictionarystr as string = "un-cen-tered"
dim Textstr as string = "uncen-tered"
```

Result: Correct breaking.

Case 2:

```
dim Dictionarystr as string = "un-cen-tered"
dim Textstr as string = "unce-ntered"
```

Result: Wrong breaking.

Comment: Define "correct" and show what you've tried

Comment: Grammatically correct.

Comment: You would need a giant dictionary containing hyphenation points for all of the different words in the English language. There's no algorithm for this, and it certainly isn't part of .NET.

Comment: Are you trying to spell check the words?

Comment: Yes, I have a list of words with proper breaking points (stored in excel file; more than 100,000 words). PDF is my input format, and my tool needs to read all the line-end hyphenated words from it. After that, I need to compare the Textstr (PDF words) against Dictionarystr (Dictionary terms) for proper breaking points. Need to write log.

Answer (score 0):

First I would compare the two words without hyphen to make sure they have the exact same letters at the right place.

Then I would count the number of letters on the left side of each hyphen (without counting hyphen). If all the numbers found in Textstr are also found in Dictionarystr then it's a match.

Ex: un-cen-tered
un (count 2 letters on the left side of the first hyphen)
uncen (count 5 letters on the left side of the second hyphen)

Case 1:

> Dictionarystr: 2, 5
>     Textstr: 5
>     * 5 is contained in the previous list, good

Case 2:

> Dictionarystr: 2, 5
>     Textstr: 4
>     * 4 is not in the previous list, bad

---

```
' This is your list of word with hyphen
Dim dictionaryWordsWithHyphen As New List(Of String)
' Pre-loaded information
Dim dictionaryWordsInfo As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Integer))

Sub Main()

    ' This is your list of word with hyphen
    dictionaryWordsWithHyphen.Add("hou-se")
    dictionaryWordsWithHyphen.Add("big-hou-se")
    dictionaryWordsWithHyphen.Add("some-made-up-word")

    ' Pre-load the information in a way that is easy to search on
    ' This should be done once at the begining of the program
    For Each word In dictionaryWordsWithHyphen
        dictionaryWordsInfo.Add(GetFullWord(word), GetLetterCount(word))
    Next

    ' Test on some words
    Console.WriteLine(IsGoodWord("does-not-exists")) ' False
    Console.WriteLine(IsGoodWord("big-hou-se")) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(IsGoodWord("bighou-se")) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(IsGoodWord("big-house")) ' True
    Console.WriteLine(IsGoodWord("bigh-ouse")) ' False
    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

Function GetFullWord(ByVal word As String) As String

    Return word.Replace("-", "")
End Function

Function GetLetterCount(ByVal word As String) As List(Of Integer)

    Dim letterCount As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim split() As String = word.Split("-")
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    For Each section As String In split
        count += section.Length
        letterCount.Add(count)
    Next

    Return letterCount
End Function

Function IsGoodWord(ByVal word As String) As Boolean

    Dim fullWord As String = GetFullWord(word)
    Dim letterCount As List(Of Integer) = GetLetterCount(word)

    ' Check if the word exists in the dictionary
    If Not dictionaryWordsInfo.ContainsKey(fullWord) Then
        Return False
    End If

    ' Check if the letter count exists
    For Each c As Integer In letterCount
        If Not dictionaryWordsInfo(fullWord).Contains(c) Then
            ' The hyphen is at the wrong place
            Return False
        End If
    Next

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Any suggestion on Regex or Linq method? For loop consume more time. 100+ words needs to be compared for each file. 1000+ files needs to be processes each day.

Comment: @PonSaravananBhoopathy no mater what you use, you have no choice but to use a loop. Even Linq will use loops. You should specify that in your question if that was important. A lot of what I wrote down can be pre-calculated. The algorithm I wrote is fast, your problem seems to be finding the right Dictionarystr value, which is a totally different question.

Comment: I have used regex using the following method:

Dim mysuffix As String = "\-?"
Dim mySearchStr As String = Regex.Replace(myFirstWord & SecondWord, "(.)", "${1}" & mysuffix)
mySearchStr = mySearchStr.Replace("\-?-\-?", "\-")

Dim myDictionaryTermSearch As Match = Regex.Match(DictionaryWord, mySearchStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)


Do you have any other alternative method?

Comment: @PonSaravananBhoopathy That's going to be a pain to figure out and it'll be slow. You should try out the algorithm I wrote down. I put up a quick console application example. It uses a hash search for the word (which is fast) and then loop in a very small array (1 to 6 items I would guess).

Comment: Thanks for the algorithm. Let me check and get back to you.